# For better performance, which is better: componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually, I have to perform heavy operations and set it as state after new data received by react component. so i am little bit worried about performance. Both "componentWillUpdate" and "componentDidUpdate" can accomplish my requirement. So, what should i use for better performance?

Comment: why not try both and test to see if there is any difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

More than the performance issues, there is a point about the differences of these two methods: If you are using setState inside your component, then using it inside componentWillUpdate will have no effect. You have to use it inside componentDidUpdate. If you are not using the setState inside component(which is my favourite), then you need to take everything via props which is appropriate for usage of both methods.
Otherwise, these two methods depend on the result of the shouldComponentUpdate() method, which decides your component needs to be updated or not. Both method will be executed if the component needs to be updated.

Comment: I found the following helpful: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html